# Ember 3.5 BelongsTo Relationships not Resolving

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

i used to have emberjs 1.13 which i upgraded to 3.5
i got an issue with belongsTo relationships where i cannot access those data in it. my code as below

model

```
export default DS.Model.extend( {

  title: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  description: DS.attr( 'string' ),
  published: DS.attr( 'boolean' ),
  publishedAt: DS.attr( 'date' ),

  course: DS.belongsTo( 'course' ),
  author: DS.belongsTo( 'profile', { async: true } ),

  viewed: false,
  isNew: true,

}
```

in controller

```
this.get('model.published') working 
this.get('model.author.name') not working
```

but the same code was working on 1.13 of emberjs

with ember data 1.13

[image]

with ember data 3.5

[image]

Comment: Is the `author` already loaded? can you reproduce in a twiddle? This looks good, it should work.

Comment: Can you show us your route `model()`, route template, route controller and author model? It looks like author is not yet present in the store. Perhaps remove async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a big upgrade from 1.13 straight to 3.5.

A lot has changed. To fully understand what changed and why, I much recommend reading each of the [Ember release notes](https://www.emberjs.com/blog/tags/releases.html) every time you upgrade a minor or major version. Super helpful.

Most likely `author` was not loaded into the store. Check your route's `model()`, network request and Ember Inspector if data loaded in.

If loaded in, it may be the `async: true`. Try remove it?

This is a working example in Ember 3.5:

`app/models/thing.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({

  // Attributes
  title: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  published: attr('string'),
  publishedAt: attr('string'),

  // Relationships:
  // No need for async: true
  course: belongsTo('course'),
  author: belongsTo('author')

});
```

`app/models/author.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
});
```

`app/route/thing.js`

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    // Assuming you use JSON API
    // Make sure `author` is included when fetching `thing`
    return this.store.query('thing', {
      include: 'author, course'
    }),
  }
});
```

`app/controllers/thing.js`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  init(){
    console.log(this.model.author.name)
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks alot for your detailed answer. but this doesn't resolve my issue of obtaining author. and for your more information i have upgraded by 1.13->2.18->3.5 but issue was there in 2.18 as well.

i have re write a detailed question again in stackoverflow. i would really appreciate if you can have a look on that 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255803/replace-ember-arraycontroller-create-will-not-resolve-belongto-relationships