# Ember 3.25 BelongsTo not sideloading

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am trying to sideload relationship data from one API call. I have a my two models setup like so:

Contest Model (child, belongsTo):

```
import Model, { attr, belongsTo } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class ContestModel extends Model {
  @attr('date') createdAt;
  @attr('string') description;

  @belongsTo('brand', { inverse: 'contests' }) brand;
}
```

Brand Model (parent, hasMany):

```
import Model, { attr, hasMany } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class BrandModel extends Model {
  @attr('date') createdAt;
  @attr('string') name;

  @hasMany('contest') contests;
}
```

I'm fetching via this line:

```
this.store.findRecord('contest', params.contest_id, { include: 'brand' });
```

This is the returned API payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "contest",
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "body_json": [
        {
          "question": "what time is it?",
          "answers": ["1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM"]
        },
        {
          "question": "which collection is this artwork from?",
          "answers": ["botanical garden collection", "ghibli collection", "adventure collection", "swag collection"]
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "2021-05-23 18:00:00 -0700",
      "description": "a good description goes here"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "brand": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/contests/2/relationships/brand" // not sure what this does
        },
        "data": { "type": "brand", "id": 2 }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/contests/2" // not sure how this is useful
    },
    "included": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "brand",
        "attributes": {
          "created_at": "2021-05-23 20:00:00 -0700",
          "name": "aloha vibe"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The issue here is that calling `myContest.brand` returns a Proxy object just like in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200940/ember-3-5-belongsto-relationships-not-resolving).

Is my API payload incorrect or is something misconfigured for my models? Or something else? I'm on `Ember 3.25.3`

Update from comments: When I add `async: false` to the Ember Data query, I get an error after this line https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v3.25.0/packages/store/addon/-private/system/model/internal-model.ts#L705 due to `toReturn.isEmpty` being true. Did I not configure my API payload? Not sure what is wrong. It seems neither `createdAt` nor `name` is populated.

[image]

Comment: `myContest.brand` is expected to be a proxy. As the record is already in the store, you should be able to access its ID (`myContest.brand.id`) or any attribute of it (`myContest.brand.name`).

Comment: you could declare `async: false`

Comment: I am unable to call `myContest.brand.id` without making a second API call

Comment: I added the `async: false` and now it says: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'brand' relationship on a 'contest' with id 1 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (\`belongsTo({ async: true })\`)`

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot and the offending line of code that caused the exception. Will keep digging but any ideas are definitely welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the bug! The data payload needs to be in this format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "contest",
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "body_json": [
        {
          "question": "what time is it?",
          "answers": ["1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM"]
        },
        {
          "question": "which collection is this artwork from?",
          "answers": ["botanical garden collection", "ghibli collection", "adventure collection", "swag collection"]
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "2021-05-23 18:00:00 -0700",
      "description": "a good description goes here"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "brand": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/brands/2"
        },
        "data": { "type": "brand", "id": 2 }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/contests/2"
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "brand",
      "attributes": {
        "created_at": "2021-05-23 20:00:00 -0700",
        "name": "aloha vibe"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I had nested the `included` within the `data` section but it should be at the top level with the `data` section. Now things are properly sideloaded and no extra API call is made :)